# How flexible can a unitary transformation be?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, linear-algebra

Let's say you have a Hamiltonian with $k$ different terms,
\begin{equation}
\hat{H}=\sum_{i=1}^k a_k \hat{O}_k
\end{equation}
with real coefficients $a_k$ and Hermitian operators $\hat{O}_k$.

Now, if there is another Hamiltonian $\hat{H}^{\prime}$ that acts on the same Hilbert space with $k$ operators that have exactly the same commutation/anticommutation relations as $\hat{H}$, is it always the case that there is a unitary transformation $U$ that connects those two? i.e.
\begin{equation}
H^{\prime}=U H U^{\dagger}.
\end{equation}

I was thinking that this should be true even with restricting $U$ to be a Clifford transformation when all $\hat{O}_k$ are (multi-qubit) Pauli operators. However, I found an exception to that, and I got confused.

(Edit)

The "exception" I thought I found turned out to be a mistake. Now I understand that whenever the above assumption is true, there should be a Clifford unitary that corresponds to the transformation. Thanks people!

Comment: Similarity transformations don't change the spectrum.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I understand that, but I'm kind of asking the reverse, and also am not exactly asking about the spectrum, although I think it's also an equally interesting question. 
So, when you have two Hamiltonians with exactly the same spectrum, is there always a similarity transformation connecting them? 

My original question was: given that the commutation relations of all terms are exactly the same, is there always a similarity transformation?